# What's the correct way of deserializing a UTxO?

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, utxo, cardano-graphql

I'm getting the following error when trying to deserialize a UTxO obtained using `cardano-graphql`:

```
Deserialization failed in TransactionUnspentOutput because: No variant matched
```

This is the code that it's failing:

```
for (const rawUtxo of rawUtxos) {
      const utxo = CardanoWasm.TransactionUnspentOutput.from_bytes(
        Buffer.from(rawUtxo.transaction.hash, "hex")
      )
      const input = utxo.input()
      const txid = input.transaction_id().to_bytes().toString();
      const txindx = input.index()
      const output = utxo.output()
      const amount = output.amount().coin().to_str() // amount in lovelace
      const multiasset = output.amount().multiasset()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to deserialize the UTxOs of an address:

```
for (const rawUtxo of rawUtxos) {
      const utxo = C.TransactionUnspentOutput.from_bytes(Buffer.from(rawUtxo, "hex"));
      const input = utxo.input();
      const txid = Buffer.from(input.transaction_id().to_bytes(), "utf8").toString("hex");
      const txindx = showPtrInHex(input.index());   
      const output = utxo.output();
      const amount = output.amount().coin().to_str(); // ADA amount in lovelace
      const multiasset = output.amount().multiasset();
      let multiAssetStr = "";

      if (multiasset) {
        const keys = multiasset.keys() // policy Ids of thee multiasset
        const N = keys.len();
    
        for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          const policyId = keys.get(i);
          const policyIdHex = Buffer.from(policyId.to_bytes(), "utf8").toString("hex");
          const assets = multiasset.get(policyId)
          const assetNames = assets.keys();
          const K = assetNames.len()

          for (let j = 0; j < K; j++) {
            const assetName = assetNames.get(j);
            const assetNameString = Buffer.from(assetName.name(), "utf8").toString();
            const assetNameHex = Buffer.from(assetName.name(), "utf8").toString("hex")
            const multiassetAmt = multiasset.get_asset(policyId, assetName)
            multiAssetStr += ` + ${multiassetAmt.to_str()} ${policyIdHex} . ${assetNameHex} (${assetNameString})`
          }
        }
      }
    
      const obj = {
        txid: txid,
        txindx: txindx,
        amount: amount,
        str: `${txid} # ${txindx} = ${amount}`,
        multiAssetStr: multiAssetStr,
        TransactionUnspentOutput: utxo
      }

      utxos.push(obj);
```